# PL/Ruby equivalent in MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby

PL/Ruby is a loadable procedural language for Postgres that lets you use Ruby to write user defined functions for the database.

Anyone know of an equivalent way of writing user defined functions for MySQL in Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from version 5 (I think) Mysql supports [stored procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines.html), but the syntax is restricted to SQL:2003 which is somewhat similar to PL/SQL.

Other languages aren't supported and I'm not aware of any projects offering ruby support. Last time I checked the PL/Ruby extensions to postgres were still a bit wonky as well, though.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql as far as I am aware only supports MySQLs own stored procedure language.

I'm a postgresql fan too, and this is something that has always frustrated me about MySQL when I have had no choice but to use it. :(